# Как мне упростить формулу добавления букв

Tags: python

```
favorite_fruits = ['papaya', 'apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'orange', 'pineapple']

x = 1

if 'banana' in favorite_fruits:
    print(f"You "
        f"{'r'+ 'e'*x + 'a'*x + 'l'*x + 'ly'}" 
        " like bananas!")
    x += 1

if 'apple' in favorite_fruits:
    print(f"You "
        f"{'r'+ 'e'*x + 'a'*x + 'l'*x + 'ly'}" 
        " like apples!")
    x += 1

if 'coconut' in favorite_fruits:
    print(f"You "
        f"{'r'+ 'e'*x + 'a'*x + 'l'*x + 'ly'}" 
        " like coconuts!")
    x += 1
```

Мне нужно упростить формулу:

`'r'+ 'e'*x + 'a'*x + 'l'*x + 'ly'`

Или найти другие способы это сделать, что бы при каждом пройденном условии добавлялась еще одна буква E, A, L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попытаться сделать так, возможно это то что вам подходит:

```py
favorite_fruits = ['papaya', 'apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'berry']
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'coconut', 'berry']
x = 1

def what_i_like(fruit):
    letters_e = 'e' * x
    letters_a = 'a' * x
    letters_l = 'l' * x
    ends_with_y = fruit.endswith('y')
    end = 'ies' if ends_with_y else 's'
    fruit_name = (fruit[0:-1] if ends_with_y else fruit) + end

    print('You r' + letters_e + letters_a + letters_l + 'ly like ' + fruit_name + '!')

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in favorite_fruits:
        what_i_like(fruit)
        x += 1
```

Я также добавил небольшую проверку, чтобы проверить, оканчивается ли название фрукта на `y`, если так, тогда окончание будет `ies`, в противоположном случае будет `s`.

Comment: как же это круто :о